# Choose the size of image matrix

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy

I work on a "detector of word" and i want to make a database with of letters.
I tried to transform a letter image (on .jpg) to Numpy matrix but the result wasn't workable.

My program with 'G' letter:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image as img
g=img.open('G.png')
tabg=np.array(g)
print(tabg,tabg.shape)
```

and the result of this program:

```
[[[255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  ...
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  ...
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  ...
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]
  ... 
 [[255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  ...
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  ...
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  ...
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]] (28, 28, 4)
```

i give my image if it can help: [G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsE76.png)

i want to transform this result on matrix size = (28,28) if it's possible.
Thanks you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean "not workable"?  What output do you want?  It looks like perfectly normal RGBA output.

Comment: I want a 28x28 matrix, how transform this RGBA output on 28x28 matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You look at your images, and recommend use cv2 from opencv lib to read it. Since it a

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

G = cv2.imread(‘%imagepath’,0) #open in gray scale or it will load the image into rgb
print(G.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the resolution is `28 px x 28 px` and 4 color dimensions. I couldn't find from the [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#image-module) what they are (probably RGBA), but maybe you just use PIL's own method to convert this image to grey scale via [`Image.convert`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image as img
g=img.open('G.png')
g=g.convert(mode="L")
tabg=np.array(g)
print(tabg,tabg.shape)
```